# Shift rows in a Column when equal to specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I want to shift `rows` in a `pandas` `df` when values are equal to a specific value in a `Column`. For the `df` below, I'm trying to shift the values in `Column B` to `Column A` when values in `A == x`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [1,'x','x','x',5],
    'B' : ['x',2,3,4,'x'],
        })
```

This is my attempt:

```
df = df.loc[df.A.shift(-1) == df.A.shift(1), 'x'] = df.A.shift(1)
```

Intended Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  x
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5  x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
m = df.A.eq('x')
df[m]=df[m].shift(-1,axis=1)
print(df)

   A    B
0  1    x
1  2  NaN
2  3  NaN
3  4  NaN
4  5    x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df[df.A=='x'] = df.shift(-1,axis=1)

print(df)

   A    B
0  1    x
1  2  NaN
2  3  NaN
3  4  NaN
4  5    x
```